# Making sure at least one instance of a base exists before creating a derived type

Tags: c++, inheritance, instance

Something that should appear to be simple has been a current stumbling block for me. I have simple inheritance, but I want to make sure that at least 1 instance of a base class exists before constructing any of its derived types:

```
class Parent {
private:
    std::string name_;

    explicit Parent( const std::string& name );

protected:
    // Constructor that Derived Types Will Use
    Parent( const std::string& parentName, const std::string& childName, bool isChildAParent = false );

};

Child : public Parent {
public:
    Child( const std::string& parentName, const std::string& childName, bool isChildAParent = false );
};

// It is here in the 2nd or protected constructor that I'm struggling with.
Parent::Parent( const std::string& parentName, const std::string& childName, bool isChildAParent ) {

    // How To Go about to check if an instance of Parent already exists that
    // used its default constructor before using this constructor from a derived type?

}
```

In the main the usages would be like this:

```
int main() {
    Child child( "parent", "child", false ); // Invalid since Parent wasn't created first

    Parent parent( "parent" );
    Child child( "parent", "child", false ); // Okay since parent exists.

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit** - Based on a comment from `Kerrek SB` stating

> I might need a static member somewhere

this is what I have done now and I am getting the behavior that I'm expecting.

**.h**

```
class Parent {
private:
    std::string myName_; // Name of this parent
    static bool isConstructed_;
    bool isParent_;
protected:
    std::string parentName_;
public:

    // This must be called first at least once before trying to create any children classes.
    // The importances of this dependence has to do with the pointer of this parent being stored
    // in a vector (outside of this class), and every child created after this will create a family that belongs to this parent.

    explicit Parent( const std::string& name ); 
    Parent( Parent &&self );
    Parent& operator=( Parent &&transfer );

    Parent( Parent const & ) = delete;
    Parent& operator=( Parent const & ) = delete;

    //*virtual*/ void print() { }


    virtual void printName() const;
    virtual void printParentName() const;

    const std::string& getName() const;
    const std::string& getParentName() const;

protected:
    // Constructor that is used when using inheritance.
    explicit Parent( const std::string& parentName, const std::string& childName, bool isChildAParent = false );
};

class Child : public Parent {
public:
    Child( const std::string& parentName, const std::string& childName, bool isChildAParent = false );
};
```

**.cpp**

```
bool Parent::isConstructed_ = false;

// Initial Constructor Must Be Called First At Least Once.
Parent::Parent( const std::string& parentName ) :
myName_( parentName ) { 
    isConstructed_ = true;
    isParent_ = true;
}

// Protected Constructor Used By Child Classes.
Parent::Parent( const std::string& parentName, const std::string& childName, bool isChildAParent ) {
    // First check to see if this child will be a parent itself
    if ( !isConstructed_ ) {
        std::cout << "There must be at least 1 instance of a Parent\n"
                  << "before constructing a child.\n";
    } else {
        myName_ = childName;
        parentName_ = parentName;
        isParent_ = isChildAParent;
    }
}

// Move Constructor
Parent::Parent( Parent&& self )  {
}

// Move Opeartor
Parent& Parent::operator=( Parent&& self ) {
    if ( this != &self ) {
    }
    return *this;
}

void Parent::printName() const {
    std::cout << myName_ << std::endl;
}

void Parent::printParentName() const {
    std::cout << parentName_ << std::endl;
}

const std::string& Parent::getName() const {
    return myName_;
}

const std::string& Parent::getParentName() const {
    return parentName_;
}

Child::Child( const std::string& parentName, const std::string& childName, bool isChildAParent ) :
Parent( parentName, childName, isChildAParent ) {
}
```

**main.cpp** - first version

```
int main() {

    Parent  p( "someParent" );
    Child   c( "someParent", "someChild" );

    // Child's Construction is successful because Parent p exists         

    return 0;
}
```

**main.cpp** - version 2

```
int main() {
    Child c( "someParent", "someChild" );

    // Still compiles and prints out the message that a parent needs to exists first
    // This can be thrown as an exception to prevent the creation
    // of a derived type without at least having a base type that already exists.

    return 0;
}
```

Thank You `Kerrek SB`.

**EDIT** -- After thinking about the relationship that I need between a `Parent` and `Child` class, I think I have came to the conclusion that it might be better to have another class that will be an `Abstract Base Class` that both the `Parent` and `Child` types would inherit from independently from each other. This way my `Manager` or `Storage` class that has the container of these would accept a `shared_ptr<base_class>` so that it can container either type, then these inherited classes `Parent` & `Child` can contain a list of `references to pointers` of the ones that they are associated with. Then it would be up to the `Manager` or `Storage` class to be responsible to check if the very first entry in its container is in fact a `Parent` type and not a `Child` type. I went ahead and added this to the original question for future references to others. I would still like some feed back on the above construct that I've just mentioned.

Comment: You'll probably need a static member somewhere.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me, what are you *actually* trying to solve?

Comment: If you change `Child`'s constructor take require a reference to a `Parent`, you can be sure that there exists a `Parent`

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The idea was or is that if one constructs a base object `Parent` they use the public constructor to create an instance of it. The protected constructor is the constructor that is used by its derived types `Child` and I want the protected constructor to check if there has been at least 1 instance of base type already created before creating an instance of a derived type.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Since derived children would be the same as a Parent object but each child could be slightly different, the reason for inheritance, however this is also going to be a nested tree structure and before a child or derived type can declared as an instance, at least one Parent must be an instance first since it would be the root of the tree.

Comment: I think Kerrek might of gave me the answer to this by using a static member. I might be able to have a static bool flag that will trigger if the public constructor was used and use that flag to determine if I can call the protected constructors.

Comment: Just knowing a `Parent` was created is pointless. If there's a practical reason then there has to be some way for the `Child` to communicate with that `Parent`. So assuming there is such a way, why can't you check the actual state?

Comment: @eran no it isn't. Can you ever have a child without first having a parent? And Kerrek has helped me with this for I now have it working.

Comment: When you create a child class, the parent has to be created, sure, but both are part of the same object. You're asking about a separate Parent object. Since this is a very unconventional use of inheritance, I really think you should present the actual use case rather than look for a particular hack. I'm glad your question was answered, but I think you could have gotten answers that would improve your solution much more, had the actual problem been described.

Comment: @eran These two types are basically the same thing except a child might have slightly different attributes than its parent/s. That is why I'm using inheritance. These objects will be stored in a tree hierarchy where at least 1 Parent needs to exists first before any Child can be constructed. That is why I have 2 constructors, 1 public for the Parent, and 1 protected that all derived types will use and I wanted the "Parent's" protected constructor to detect if an instance already exists. This way I don't have to be concerned about that when added them to the tree.

Comment: @eran I do know that when a Child is constructed that it will call the Parent constructor through inheritance. That isn't the issue. The issue is when a Child calls it's constructor it will use the protected version of the Parent's constructor and not it's public version. The public version is used to create an instance of a Parent type where the Children have a matching public constructor to the Parent's protected one. I needed this protected constructor in the Parent class to check if an instance of a Parent type exists at least once before calling the protected version.

Comment: This is not an X/Y problem.

Comment: WHY must an instance of the base type exist before any instance of the derived type be created? It is not obvious to us what scenarios might exist that would require this. This is not common, let alone recommended. The derived type Child should inherit the base type Parent to implement that type.

Comment: I have another class that will contain `vector<shared_ptr<Parent>>` the very first shared pointer must be an actual Parent and not a Child, where each one after can be either a Parent or a Child. in this tree or container, thus the need of making sure at least one Parent instance exists first via the calling of the public constructor. Another way of putting it is; the Children have a public constructor that calls the Parent's protected constructor. This protected construct has to be called after at least 1 public constructor call has already been made.

Answer (score 0):

Give the base class Parent a static integer object that is incremented in its constructor:

```
class Parent{
    public:
        Parent(){instances++;}
        ~Parent(){instances--;}
        unsigned int instances(){return instances;}
    private:
        static unsigned int instances = 0;
```

Then, throw an exception in the Child class if instances = 0:

```
class Child : public Parent{
    public:
        Child(){if(Parent::instances() == 0){throw "message"};
```

According to [this wiki entry](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#ctors-can-throw), using `throw` in the class' constructor is the standard way of preventing object instantiation, both for stack and heap allocation. The `static` member object in `Parent` is just used to keep a running tally of the total number of instances.

Comment: I don't need to know how many or to keep track, I just need to know if at least 1 instance of Parent exists first. But thank you for the attempt.

Comment: This is a perfectly adequate method of achieving your stated goal.

Comment: Yes, but just having a single static Boolean worked. If the Public constructor of Parent was called, the flag is set to true. Then if a Derived type that uses the Base type's protected constructor is being called, it will check that static bool to see if at least one instance already exists.

Comment: @FrancisCugler That works, but what if those Parent objects go out of scope or are deleted? You need to change the boolean value to false; but how do you keep track of all the instances? Deleting one does not necessarily mean there aren't any Parents still in scope, so the instances variable helps you keep track. Probably a boolean based way of doing this, but this is the most common sense method to me.

Comment: I might rethink my design pattern and might just do away with inheritance altogether, and just add a flag into the class to indicate if this particular instance is either a parent or a child to remove that dependency. Then just have the manager class, tree-list structure manage their associations.